# Sails.js + passport twitter crashes after first login

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-generate-auth

I am using sails.js v0.12.1 with this package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-generate-auth

My passport packages are:
"sails-generate-auth": "^0.3.1",
"passport": "^0.3.2"
"bcryptjs": "^2.3.0",
"passport-http-bearer": "^1.0.1",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0",
"passport-twitter": "^1.0.4",

I've got my client id and secret setup for twitter and the login works great the first time. If I then logout and try to login again, sails crashes and I get the following error:

```
api/services/passport.js:154
          User.findOne(passport.user.id, next);
                               ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
```

This file has been generated when installing the package, so nothing I've tampered with. I am new to sails and passport so maybe I have done something wrong, but I find it weird that it works the first time.

To get it working again I need to restart sails and ask it to drop my database, then it works.

My user model looks like this:

```
var User = {
  // Enforce model schema in the case of schemaless databases
  schema: true,

  attributes: {
    username  : { type: 'string', unique: true },
    email     : { type: 'email',  unique: true },
    passports : { collection: 'Passport', via: 'user' }
  }
};

module.exports = User;
```

Thanks for the help!
Let me know if any info is missing to solve the problem.

Comment: Have you set `passport` policies for the routes? Also there is a bug with sails-generate-auth In the line 154, it should be `User.findOne(passport.user, next);` not `passport.user.id`

Comment: @MjZac Yes I've set the policies, but didn't know about the bug, will try it out, thanks!